# AngularJS scroll directive - How to prevent re-rendering whole scope

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I have an AngularJS Application with a scroll directive implemented as the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/un6r4wts/

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.run(function ($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.var1 = 'Var1';
    $rootScope.var2 = function () { return Math.random(); };

});

app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
                 scope.scrolled = true;
            } else {
                 scope.scrolled = false;
            }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

The HTML looks the following:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" scroll ng-class="{scrolled:scrolled}">
    <header></header>
    <section>
        <div class="vars">
        {{var1}}<br/><br/>
        {{var2()}}
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I only want the class scrolled to be added to the div once the page is scrolled more than 100px. Which is working just fine, but I ***only*** want that to happen! I don't want the whole scope to be re-rendered. So the function var2() should not be executed while scrolling. Unfortunately it is though.

Is there any way to have angular only execute the function which is bound to the window element without re-rendering the whole scope, or am I misunderstanding here something fundamentally to AngularJS?

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/un6r4wts/

Edit:
This seems to be a topic about a similar problem:
[Angularjs scope.$apply in directive's on scroll listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833219/angularjs-scope-apply-in-directives-on-scroll-listener)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate an expression only once, you can prefix it with '::', which does exactly that. See it in docs under One-time binding:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Note, this requires angular 1.3+.

The reason that the expressions are calculated is because when you change a property value on your scope, then dirty check starts and evaluates all the watches for dirty check. When the view uses {{ }} on some scope variable, it creates a binding (which comes along with a watch).